# Sending datagram - network unreachable

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to broadcast udp packets between two Android devices on a hotspot.

I have a client that set up the hotspot, and a server that is connected to the hotspot. Sending a package from the client and receiving that packet on the server is working. But when I try to reply from the server, I get a SocketException, saying network is unreachable. I've checked the IP address and port number and both should be correct (I'm assuming the port is correct because it was taken from the packet itself).

The code for the server and client is below. Can anyone see where the code is going wrong or if it's just a network connectivity issue?

Client:

```
    try {
            //Open a random port to send the package
            c = new DatagramSocket();
            c.setBroadcast(true);

            byte[] sendData = "DISCOVER_MV_REQUEST".getBytes();

            try {
                InetAddress addr = getIpAddress();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, getBroadcast(addr), 8888);
                c.send(sendPacket);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                c.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            // Broadcast the message over all the network interfaces
            Enumeration interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = (NetworkInterface) interfaces.nextElement();

                if (networkInterface.isLoopback() || !networkInterface.isUp()) {
                    continue; // Don't want to broadcast to the loopback interface
                }

                for (InterfaceAddress interfaceAddress : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
                    InetAddress broadcast = interfaceAddress.getBroadcast();
                    if (broadcast == null) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Send the broadcast package!
                    try {
                        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, broadcast, 8888);
                        c.send(sendPacket);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        c.close();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }

                }
            }

            //Wait for a response
            byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
            c.receive(receivePacket);

            //Check if the message is correct
            String message = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();
            if (message.equals("DISCOVER_MV_RESPONSE")) {
                //DO SOMETHING WITH THE SERVER'S IP (for example, store it in your controller)
                Log.v("SOCKET", "got correct response");
                c.close();
                return "correct";
            } else {
                c.close();
                Log.v("SOCKET", "wrong response");
                return "wrong";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Server:

```
        try {
            //Keep a socket open to listen to all the UDP trafic that is destined for this port
            socket = new DatagramSocket(8888, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
            socket.setBroadcast(true);

            while (true) {
                //Receive a packet
                byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);

                //See if the packet holds the right command (message)
                String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
                if (message.equals("DISCOVER_MV_REQUEST")) {
                    byte[] sendData = "DISCOVER_MV_RESPONSE".getBytes();

                    //Send a response
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
                    socket.send(sendPacket); //where the error happens
                    socket.close();
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You need to check the routing table to see if the local network is in it. You may only have a default route to the Internet, and not a route to the local network.

Comment: I looked at the routing table for my Android device that I generally test the server on. It says the interface is wlan0 and the destination is 0000A8C0, which I converted to 0.0.168.192. However, I'm not so sure what this means exactly...

Comment: Actually, I looked at the table while it was connected to the other phone's hotspot and the destination for wlan0 is 002BA8C0, which converts to 0.43.168.192. The ip address that the server is sending to is 192.168.43.1. Shouldn't this work?